# Ubuntu partition merge with windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

I had 2 partitions more or less 225GB each one. In the first partiton I had installed Windows 8 and in the second I have installed Ubuntu 14.0 2. My problem is that when I installed Ubuntu in the second partition everything went fine (I could access to windows) but now I can't access Windows and Ubuntu shows me that there is only a partition (450GB partition that belongs to Ubuntu). How can I fix my trouble? I tried reinstalling grub with [BootRepair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader).

Answer (score 0):

Did you by chance select the installation option that repartitions your entire hard disk? I made that mistake before. Did you choose "Other" or did you just install? It sounds like you've overwritten your entire drive.

Comment: I installed in the second partition because I had access to windows after the installation (changing boot disk in the BIOS). It is possible that this problem appear after making an update and upgrade? I figured that maybe the Grub spoiled the partitions.

Comment: It shouldn't be due to an upgrade/update since it would only affect the partitions connected to Ubuntu.